# iphone bluetooth getting an event or data from a device

Tags: iphone, events, bluetooth, mfi

I'm new to bluetooth.  Is there a way through an API call or callback to get some event from a device that's connected via BT to the iphone?  That is, without using the apple authentication chip?
A simple example would be an accessory that acts as a doorbell.  My device would send "something" to the iphone to tell it someone pressed the doorbell button.

Comment: have you find a solution for your question yet?

Answer (score 0):

No - your accessory has to be MFi compliant